# How to add on update attribute on current_timestamp sequelize cli?

Tags: javascript, node.js, orm, sequelize.js

How to add on update attribute to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` on sequelize cli?
I used

```
defaultValue:sequelize.literal('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP')
```

to get the timestamp.

Comment: Does sequelize's built in create/update timestamp support not fit your case? http://sequelize.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/models-definition/#definition

Comment: It auto generates the CreatedAt and UpdatedAt fields but doesn't have any default value. I am currently doing it my manually setting it in my schema.